# Using CoreData along with a bundled SQLite database?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I’m new to the iOS dev party so now I’m struggling with some issues. I want to create an app that uses a database for returning some information to the user. For this I added a SQLite database into the project and used this (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).

Now I want to add a new feature to the application that will let the user add some bookmarks in order to save some pieces of that information. For this, I need to update the database which is causing me some major concerns: how can I update the app without overwriting the user’s bookmarks? What happens if the user skipped two updates prior to the 3rd one? As you can see, this can turn into a huge pain.

So I was thinking on using this bundled SQLite database only as a readonly db and along with it to use CoreData for storing the user’s bookmarks. What do you think? Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Core data as you know is a persistant data that will be with your application. Well i still cant understand what seems to be the problem with maintaining the SQLite database but if this is a problem then i dont think core data will solve it. Having core data along with the SQLite database with you explicitly not chaning the DB and just "remembering" bookmarks in core data and fetching them from SQLite might do the trick. This is a conceptual problem that you are facing.

Comment: My main problem comes with updating the application. Imagine that I need to modify something in the database. I don't have any experience with this but wouldn't this update overwrite the user's local database? If so, this means that all his bookmarks will be deleted.

Comment: application database as in server side?\

Comment: Care to be more specific? I don't quite understand the question. (sorry, I'm a beginner developer)

Comment: Your database as in are you using a local database only for the phone. or your application is connecting to a server to fetch data and store them locally?

Comment: I'm using a local pre-populated database only for the phone. I was thinking on using Parse.com for this but I wanted to keep my project as simple as possible in order focus on learning the basics.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is a great framework, but it is not trivial and it add complexity that maybe is not required from your project.

If the bookmarks are not a lot of data you could store them in the NSUserDefaults.

this example can be useful :
(http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/)